# Google Cloud Translation - Work around for glossaries limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, translation, google-translate, language-translation, google-translation-api

After looking around the glossary feature for Cloud Translation, I was surprised with the limit of 1000 glossaries per GCP project. I wonder if there are any direct solutions or work arounds for this limitation. Even maybe without using GCP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google cloud translation has limit of 1000 glossaries per GCP project. But, if you report your issue in GCP console support (or) report an issue in public issue tracker https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers maybe based on your business requirements, they will try to increase your glossaries.

**Additional Information:**

As in the documentation, The maximum number of glossaries for a Google Cloud project is 1000. If you reach this limit, you must delete existing glossaries to create new ones[1].

You can use list glossaries[2] to get the number of glossaries you have.

You can delete glossaries[3] that were not at use in production application.

[1]. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary

[2]. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#list-glossaries

[3]. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#delete-glossary

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 1000 glossaries yes, but this number is the maximum number of glossary collections - for management purpose.

Within each glossary, you can have a lot of terms. According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#:%7E:text=the%20total%20number%20of%20terms%20in%20an%20glossary%20input%20file%20can%27t%20exceed%2010.4%20million),

> the total number of terms in an glossary input file can't exceed 10.4
> million (10,485,760) UTF-8 bytes for all terms in all the languages
> combined. Any single glossary term must be less than 1024 UTF-8 bytes.
> Terms longer than 1024 bytes are ignored.